# is_dir, scandir on local network

Tags: php

On my computer, I run Wamp on Windows 7 x64. Files are base in DocumentRoot and I have an alias that leads to another directory on my f: drive.

On my network, I have other computers. When typing in any explorer the address http://192.168.x.x/htmlbase/ it correctly shows the content of the directory htmlbase, as specified by my alias.

On my network, I also have a Synology, running Apache. On that very Synology, I have a php script that should actually scan the content of htmlbase on MY computer, so on 192.168.x.x/htmlbase/ and print the list of directories and files.

The problem is that everything fails, it won't read it:

Sources I have tried:

```
'//192.168.x.x/htmlbase/'
'http://192.168.x.x/htmlbase/'
'file://192.168.x.x/htmlbase/'
"\\\\192.168.x.x\\htmlbase\\"
```

a simple

```
if (is_dir($source))
    echo 'yes';
else
    echo 'no';
```

will always  echo 'no'.

And scandir fails telling me that

```
"Warning: scandir(//192.168.x.x/htmlbase/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /volume1/web/htmlreader/index.php on line 68 Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in /volume1/web/htmlreader/index.php on line 68"
```

I've read other topics telling that the Apache server on my Synology doesn't have the required rights to scan a directory on my computer, but nothing more.

Comment: `scandir()` doesn't support `http` AFAIK, do you have a network drive? Otherwise why don't you use FTP?

Comment: Why would I use FTP in the other hand? I need to list the directories and files in that directory, and make them clickable to browse them. If it's a file I parse it and render it according to my parsing...

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a service like Samba running and configured to be able to browse directories.

https://www.samba.org/

Does Synology have Samba, and if so is that service running?

Comment: Synology has SMB enabled, even SMB2 and larget MTU yes. The service is running actually on it. But i'm trying to access my computer from a script running on the synology, not inverse

Comment: Ok, both of your computers would need to be in the same workgroup. Can you check to see if both of them are in the same workgroup?

Comment: Are both computers permissions/firewalls set to allow file sharing?

Comment: What/where does php need permissions to access an apache directory?

btw, just tried is_dir from a script running on my computer to the synology, doesn't work either... Nor scandir

Comment: It's not PHP permissions, it is the computers permissions, are the ports open than Samba uses to communicate on both computers, are there any special permission you have to configure to allow file sharing.